# Postgres pg_dump times out

Tags: database, postgresql, webfaction

I am running this command on Webfaction:

`ionice -c2 -n6 pg_dump --blobs -U mhjohnson_flavma -f dump.sql`

pg_dump: SQL command failed
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout

Any ideas on how to change the timeout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your server probably has statement-timeouts configured in one way or another. (cf. [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT))

As a quick solution, you could use `PGOPTIONS="-c statement_timeout=0" pg_dump [...]` to temporarily overwrite this setting for the dumping process.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `alter user [user_name] set statement_timeout = 0;` worked for me.